# Omit fields recursively if so specified in another object?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to omit fields from an object recursively if the given field was specified in another object?

I want to specify what fields I'd like to receive from an API call and then have TypeScript type it correctly (dropping the fields that were never specified in the API call).

```js
interface Person {
  head: {
    hairColor: string
    eyeColor: string
  }
}

const person: Person = {
  head: {
    hairColor: 'gray',
    eyeColor: 'green',
  }
}

// Converts all values in an object to boolean (recursively)
type BooleanValues<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? BooleanValues<T[K]> : boolean
}

const fieldsToInclude: BooleanValues<Person> = {
  head: {
    hairColor: true,
    // No need to specify 'false' values. Unspecified fields should default to 'false' and be omitted.
  }
}

dropFields(person, fieldsToInclude)

function dropFields<T>(x: T, y: BooleanValues<T>): IncludeFieldsBasedOn<T, typeof y> {
  return // ...
}
```

How do you type the `IncludeFieldsBasedOn<T, U>` ?

I tried this, but couldn't get it to work due to type errors:

```js
type IncludeFieldsBasedOn<T, O extends BooleanValues<T>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? IncludeFieldsBasedOn<T[K], O[K]> : O[K] extends true ? T[K] : never
}
```

The problem above is that it doesn't understand that `O[K]` would 'match' what's in the `T` type.

Comment: I couldn't understand why are you doing this. What are you trying to achieve? You want to have optional fields, that you might drop?

Comment: I added a note at the top about the use case.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9QvqN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame almost perfect. However, if I specify `const fieldsToInclude: BooleanValues<Person>` with the type information, then this approach no longer works. The annoyance is, without this type information, tsc will not check that I have specified correct boolean fields (I could accidentally typo a field name for example). Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: you need literal types, if you assign a type it won' be a literal. You can use satisfies operator to ensure the type safety. Like in [here](https://tsplay.dev/mMOA6w). Would it work?

Comment: @wonderflame Yes `satisfies` will do just fine. Thanks! If you want to clarify this in an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: @wonderflame I noticed there's one more small thing. If you add an optional `beardColor?: string;` for the `Person` type, then it no longer autocompletes nor allows me to specify `beardColor: true` in the fields. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/NlM9Rm) should work fine. If it works, will write an answer explaining

Comment: @wonderflame Check this updated version: https://tsplay.dev/wRjLxw (scroll to very bottom) as you can see the optional field is still an issue.

Comment: oops, sorry. Check [this](https://tsplay.dev/WobBPm)

Comment: Ok this is working. Thank you so much! Do you want to wrap it up in an answer?

Comment: sure, will do when I get a chance ( probably in couple of hours )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are assigning a type to your variables, which no longer makes the literal values, which prevents the compiler from understanding the exact shape of the objects. This can be fixed by using [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const person = {
  head: {
    hairColor: 'gray',
    eyeColor: 'green',
  },
} as const

const fieldsToInclude = {
  head: {
    hairColor: true,
  },
} as const
```

However, this way you won't have the type-safety, since there is no type, which can be fixed by using the [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator:

```
const person = {
  head: {
    hairColor: 'gray',
    eyeColor: 'green',
  },
} as const satisfies Person;

const fieldsToInclude = {
  head: {
    hairColor: true,
  },
} as const satisfies BooleanValues<Person>;
```

Now, let's modify the `IncludeFieldsBasedOn` and the first thing will be removing the constraint from the `O` parameter since we can go without it and to make the type-checking easier:

```
type IncludeFieldsBasedOn<T, O> = {
  [K in keyof O as K extends keyof T
    ? O[K] extends true
      ? K
      : O[K] extends object
      ? K
      : never
    : never]: K extends keyof T
    ? NonNullable<T[K]> extends object
      ? IncludeFieldsBasedOn<NonNullable<T[K]>, O[K]>
      : T[K]
    : never;
}
```

Instead of mapping through `T` we map through the keys of `O` and by using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) we remove the fields which are false or not an object in the `O`. In the values we whether `K` is a key of `T` and if yes, we check whether it is an object. In that case, we call the `IncludeFieldsBasedOn` recursively for that object property.

Note that the usage of built-in [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type is necessary for optional fields to make sure that conditions work properly.

Usage:

```
function dropFields<T, K extends BooleanValues<T>>(
  value: T,
  x: K,
): IncludeFieldsBasedOn<T, K> {
  return {} as any; // ...
}
```

Testing:

```
// const result: IncludeFieldsBasedOn<{
//   readonly head: {
//       readonly hairColor: "gray";
//       readonly eyeColor: "green";
//   };
// }, {
//   readonly head: {
//       readonly hairColor: true;
//   };
// }>
const result = dropFields(person, fieldsToInclude);
```

The resulted type is not showing the end result, which can be fixed by using the [Prettify](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/prettify.d.ts?plain=1#L15) utility type from the [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai) package, that improves the readability of types:

```
type IncludeFieldsBasedOn<T, O> = Prettify<{
  [K in keyof O as K extends keyof T
    ? O[K] extends true
      ? K
      : O[K] extends object
      ? K
      : never
    : never]: K extends keyof T
    ? NonNullable<T[K]> extends object
      ? IncludeFieldsBasedOn<NonNullable<T[K]>, O[K]>
      : T[K]
    : never;
}>
```

Testing:

```
// const result: {
//   readonly head: {
//       readonly hairColor: "gray";
//   };
// }
const result = dropFields(person, fieldsToInclude);
```

Looks good!

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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-lI9QajWgAGLDdOAzpegDyAlh5TgS4RmVQGCweChVrg6MxcBxuDxG6bcAxLLZHNPuPxMKqvI3DMcrKa98daBfSj5aJ-nA2hLu+t5fpypznDAQEAUB2geksUAvghaBIYS2g3p+7JdGeF7Pg4fKiuKJg0nSMIMky2H3ly0GwXAE6Gsas4ahyC7huoK4ihSVKkZK0qMuuoEynC8EEgyKFwIhIgxCOvDYKw+pYHIcDqKQYAsema7Xh+d5dgKhx9jswrwnCjxRFs-baDCzpwMymGVN82iMVOmlsYunGrjZ14Ioe6AwOw8gIB0qwCLg3BwK60bRbwsTTLMLZwOgDAFpa8W6OgGhyF82QWgoroOEomXqNl+A2nabjaAARCUTC4FVfAFdE6WxIlyUFoiqnqW5DCPCkaTrmmWq6vqTFoN8kyCMIogSFIACCAgQDAqhQFkwiWCSh5KPZfqeBEL4+NoFDqJ06gUK0sVxApSnACp2AYOIygACJMDATDTqQIBzWAwBQlhen8j2RnQgtS0rXCZk7WiTkMaNrlzu5HFcaDy0iOuaK+VE-mBYgIUHGFkWzNF9ZxYlJ1vZ190wI9L1vR9ZDfcAjwIOtMCWnZ2g-oQBC-PEiT3NGZg2I85NMNGrPBNGzK80AA)

Comment: Ah I just realized one more thing. If `Person` type had an *array* field `houses: { address: string; age: number }[]`, you can't write: `const fieldsToInclude = { houses: { age: true } }`. I will try to adapt your solution to this format unless you can think of a quick solution here?

Comment: By the way, do you know if Prettify has a any significant tsc performance impact?

Comment: I'm currently on mobile, but you can check this condition `T extends readonly unknown[]` if the `T extends object` is true`. If T extends array then use T[K] as value, otherwise call recursively. No, prettify hasn't significant impact